# Create multiple attributes using a single parameter in python dataclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-dataclasses

I want to create multiple attributes using a single parameter in python dataclasses but it ends up showing an error

-This is my Code

```py
@dataclass
class Human:
    name: str
    age: int 
    birthyear:int=2022-age

h1 = Human("john", 35)
print(h1.birthyear)
```

-This error ends up showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Taha\Programs\Python\projects\UNO\tests.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Human:
  File "D:\Taha\Programs\Python\projects\UNO\tests.py", line 8, in Human
    yearOfBirth :int= 2022-age
NameError: name 'age' is not defined
```

I want to create a class like this

```py
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.birthyear = 2022 - age
```

**OR**

```py
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, age, birthyear=2022):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.birthyear = birthyear - age
```

Comment: I think dataclasses do not support this behaviour in a form you expect, take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207628/initialize-multiple-variables-to-the-same-initial-value
Post init processing might help you: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing